# Chinese input no longer working

Tags: unity, ibus, input-method, chinese

I have been mucking about when I installed Chinese input in Ubuntu 18.04. I switched a few times between fcitx and ibus, liking neither, and ended up settling on fcitx anyway.

A few months later, Chinese input no longer works and in the Language Support control panel (I prefer Unity over GNOME3) the Input Method select box (which lets me select ibus, fcitx and a few other options) does not keep its value. Upon reopening the dialog, my previously confirmed selection is gone.

Any help? Or any instructions on how to completely reset the input method to 'factory settings'?

Answer (score 0):

Seems having custom stuff in ~/.xinputrc was the culprit. But no error message in the GUI, only when running `im-config -n ibus` did it show a warning.